# Line segment in a triangle

Tags: c++, geometry

How can we check if a line segment falls partially or fully inside a triangle?

Cheers.

Comment: @Goz: Why only limit to 2D or 3D? It's clearly not 1D, but why not 4D or above? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the function for the line from the end points of the line segment. Check where this line crosses any of the sides of the triangle.

If any part of the line segment is inside the triangle, the line will either pass in through one side and out through another, or it will pass exactly along one side of the triangle and pass through two of it's corners.

If the line passes through the triangle, you compare the points where the line crosses the triangle sides (or corners) with the end points of the segment, to see if the segment is part of the line that crosses the triangle.

Comment: @Goz: Yes, the question doesn't make sense if d > 2.

Comment: See if both points lie inside triangle, then line segment must lie inside triangle! :-) See my answer!

Comment: @mag: That only works for line segments that falls fully inside the triangle. The line segment can still fall partly inside the triangle when one or both end points are outside the triangle.

Answer (score 2):

For checking if a line is fully inside a triangle, you need to check whether both end points of the line segment are located inside of the triangle.
Checking if a point is inside of a triangle can be done using techniques described [here](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html).

Checking if a segment intersects the triangle partially is a bit more complex, since checking its end points may not be enough. There are two possible cases of partial intersection:

1. One end point is inside of the triangle, and the other isn't
2. Both end points are outside of the triangle, but the segment crosses at least one of the triangle sides.

Checking 1. can be done by [this](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html) technique. Checking 2. can be done by algorithms that check whether two segments intersect. One example of how it can be done is [here](http://bloggingmath.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/line-segment-intersection/).

Comment: That doesn't necessarily work it is possible for both points to be outside the triangle and for the line to still intersect it.

Comment: OIC, this would mean that a line is partially inside a triangle, and I answered only about the "fully". Thanks for the comment, I'll try to improve my answer .....

Answer (score 1):

If one of the points of the segment is inside of the triangle => partially, if both are => fully

Point O is inside of the triangle if and only if the sum of angles AOB, BOC, COA equals 360 deg.

Cheers,

Gleb

Comment: Yes, but the line segment can also pass through the triangle with both end points being outside the triangle.

Comment: Oh yeah, you need to check line eq. as well

Answer (score -1):

Better algorithm follows:

**Why not do this:**

- If both end points of the line segment lie inside or on triangle, then line segment must lie on or inside triangle.

To check if a point lie inside triangle:

- Stand at the point, look at each vertex of the triangle
- If you look at each vertex in clockwise / anticlockwise direction then you are inside or outside